# SQLite3 not updating in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a table called Budgets that stores its settings, values, and a purchases nsarray full of the object purchases.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my method right here, but it will not update the database on an existing entry. It saves a new budget just fine.

```
- (BOOL) saveBudget:(Budget *)budget
{
    BOOL success = false;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (budget.budgetID > 0) {
            NSLog(@"Existing data, Update Please");
            NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE BUDGETS set name = '%@', budget = '%@', customdate = '%d', customday = '%d', rolloverp = '%d', rollovern = '%d', purchases = ?8 WHERE id = ?", budget.name, budget.budget, budget.customDate, budget.customDay, budget.rolloverP, budget.rolloverN];
            const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, budget.budgetID);
            sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 8, [budget.purchases bytes], [budget.purchases length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                success = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"New data, Insert Please");
            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO BUDGETS (name, budget, customdate, customday, rolloverp, rollovern, purchases) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%d\", \"%d\", \"%d\", \"%d\", ?8)", budget.name, budget.budget, budget.customDate, budget.customDay, budget.rolloverP, budget.rolloverN];
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 8, [budget.purchases bytes], [budget.purchases length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                success = true;
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSLog(@"Save Success");
    }
    return success;
}
```

I am assuming that the query is incorrect, but I may be wrong.

EDIT:
Here is how I am adding the database. Again, new entries are added and retrieved from the database just fine. Old entries are retrieved but will not update.

```
- (void) initDatabase
{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                    [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"budget.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString sql_stmt = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BUDGETS (";
            sql_stmt = [sql_stmt stringByAppendingString:@"id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "];
            sql_stmt = [sql_stmt stringByAppendingString:@"name TEXT, "];
            sql_stmt = [sql_stmt stringByAppendingString:@"budget DOUBLE, "];
            sql_stmt = [sql_stmt stringByAppendingString:@"customdate INTEGER, "];
            sql_stmt = [sql_stmt stringByAppendingString:@"customday INTEGER, "];
            sql_stmt = [sql_stmt stringByAppendingString:@"rolloverp INTEGER, "];
            sql_stmt = [sql_stmt stringByAppendingString:@"rollovern INTEGER, "];
            sql_stmt = [sql_stmt stringByAppendingString:@"purchases BLOB)"];

            if (sqlite3_exec(database, [sql_stmt UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table BUDGETS");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"BUDGETS table created successfully");
            }
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }
}
```

ANOTHER QUESTION:
I also have a question on whether I am saving the purchases NSArray correctly or not. I assumed that this would work.

Comment: Where is the database file located? It has to in document directory since the application bundle ins read only

Comment: Could you share the log output? Have you made sure that your database is stored in a writable location? If you bundle it with the app, it will be read-only, unless you copy it to the home folder for the app or some other writable location.

Comment: Typically this symptom is due to attempting to access the database out of the bundle, vs copying it to read/write storage first.

Comment: I added the code for how I add or check for an existing database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. There were no single quotes around ?8 in the update statement. Well, its always the small problems. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Location your pointing to the SQlite data base is right.And before executing the query make sure the table is in open state and ready to the operation. Refer this code:

```
        sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
        sqlite3 *cPDB;
        NSString *docsDir;
        NSArray *dirPaths;

        dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
         // Data base path 
        databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"cPDB.db"]];

     const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &cPDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE USER_SESSION_INFO SET \"%@\" = \"%@\", synState = 'false' WHERE sessionName=\"%@\"",categoryTy,state,sessionName];


        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(cPDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if((sqlite3_step(statement)) != SQLITE_DONE)
                NSLog(@"Not Updated");
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Succesfully updated row !");
                return YES;
            }
        } 

    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am already doing everything here. I just posted how I am currently checking and adding a database and it looks the same.